# Image subtraction on two copies of same images is not giving a zero matrix?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, video-processing

I am writing a code to extract frames from a video and subtract every two consecutive frames so that I'll get to know at what position the motion in the image actually starts. According to my knowledge, I should be getting an all-zero matrix after the subtraction of these frames(if they are equal). To test this I made a video on adobe premiere pro that has a static image extended for 5 seconds. After extracting the starting frames form the video, I sent them to this function but it is showing that there are multiple non-zero elements in the matrix meaning that the images are different. I am confused, please help. 
P.S: will there be any meta-data that is stored in the images itself and is this error due to that?

This the code I am using to extract the frames from the images:-

```
enter code here
import cv2
import math
videoname = "mod_vdo.mp4"
imagesloc = "C:\\Users\\ANJANIPRASAD\\PycharmProjects\\Sin\\frames1"
vdoobject = cv2.VideoCapture(videoname)
fr = vdoobject.get(5) #gets the frame rate of the video
print(fr)
success = 1
frameCount = vdoobject.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
frc=math.floor(fr)
duration=math.floor(frameCount/fr)
print(duration)
x=1
while x<=duration and success:
# vidObj object calls read
# function extract frames
frameId = vdoobject.get(1)
success, image = vdoobject.read()

if (frameId % frc == 0): #if fr is 24fps, 24rth, 48th, 72 etc will be extracted one by one
    filename = imagesloc + "/image_" + str(int(x)) + ".jpg";x=x+1
    cv2.imwrite(filename, image)
vdoobject.release()
print("Done!")
```

This extracts one frame every second(The last frame of every second to be exact)

This is the code I am using to compare the frames:

```
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing import image

dir="C:\\Users\\ANJANIPRASAD\\PycharmProjects\\Sin\\frames1"
j=1
for filename in os.listdir(dir):
 if filename.endswith('.jpg'):
    im1 = cv2.imread(dir + '/image_'+str(j)+'.jpg')
    im2= cv2.imread(dir+'/image_'+str(j+1)+'.jpg')
    if im1.shape==im2.shape:
        diff=cv2.subtract(im1,im2)
        b,g,r=cv2.split(diff)
        if cv2.countNonZero(b)==0 and cv2.countNonZero(g)==0 and 
         cv2.countNonZero(r)==0:
            j=j+1
            continue
        else:
            print('Start from the frame '+str(j)+' as the consecutive frames 
      are different')
            break
```

I am getting that 287829 different pixels between these images.
Here are the images:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1t14fpcQImVldIrxW0C1Zvz3MWMliDWUr

Comment: change format: `JPG` => `PNG`

Comment: Thank you it worked when I skipped the checking of the initial frames and when I started to check from the 3rd frame. I initialized j to 3. Maybe some extra metadata is being stored in the first 2 extracted frames because even the amount of MB they're occupying is also different.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code using the `image_1` file you provided and a copy of that file, instead of the `image_2` file.  I received a 0 difference in pixels, which tells me that the code does what you intended it to, but the two image files you are comparing are not in fact identical.  Your OpenCV code to extract and save the frames from video looks fine to me (though there is no need for the `x` variable in the `while` command, as the `success` flag already captures the end of the video), so I suspect that there is something going on with the video generation you described.

Comment: Hi, I was using x condition to check the duration because sometimes more frames than the required length are getting extracted.

Comment: It worked when I skipped the checking of the initial frames and when I started to check from the 3rd frame. I initialized j to 3. Maybe some extra metadata is being stored in the first 2 extracted frames because even the amount of MB they're occupying is also different.

Answer (score 0):

It worked when I skipped the checking of the initial frames and when I started to check from the 3rd frame. I initialized j to 3. Maybe some extra metadata is being stored in the first 2 extracted frames because even the amount of MB they're occupying is also different.

Comment: It's not file format metadata. That never affects pixel colours. Your shared two pictures really are different (used Photoshop "Difference" blend mode to check). Not all pixels match (pic1 vs pic2). Maybe the third frame onwards are better matches but only you can know that...

Comment: I don't know why it is happening, I made that video from a static image of a coffee cup. Then do you any reason for the photos being different, like maybe during the image frame extraction, something got altered?